# Changing variable values with functions in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

Like, I ll write a simple program for explanation.

```
hi=1
hii=2

def change():
    hi=3
    hii=4
    
for i in range(0,1):
    change()
    print(hi,hii)
```

Output is 1 2

But I want 3 4.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `global` to achieve this but keep in mind that this is not a recommended practice because of the overhead global bring with itself:

```
hi=1
hii=2

def change():
    global hi, hii
    hi=3
    hii=4
    
for i in range(0,1):
    change()
    print(hi, hii)
```

Comment: By overhead, do you mean the computational cost? If so, can you please explain why?

Comment: Not computational cost but code management overhead since there can be many methods that can change the global variable and it becomes difficult to debug whenever there are issues.

Answer (score 1):

You need to re-assign those values:

```py
def change()
    return 3, 4

hi = 1
hii = 2

print(hi, hii)
1 2

hi, hii = change()

print(hi, hii)
3 4
```

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to find a way without using return.. But thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

You must make the variables global first like as below

```
def change():
    global hi
    global hii
    hi=3
    hii=4
```